Qt HoverEnter event only works when the widget is clicked
I am trying to change the icon of a QPushButton at the hover event.
The issue is Qt HoverEnter event only works when the widget is clicked.
This code work with my configuration: https://gist.github.com/peteristhegreat/d6564cd0992351f98aa94f869be36f77
(from How do I implement QHoverEvent in Qt?).
So I don't get why it doesn't work in my case. Maybe I'm missing an event propagation flag between my QGraphicsScene and my QPushButton.
It is confusing because I already successfully made a code to handle QEvent::HoverEnter, but for a scrollarea.
This code is working as a stand alone, but in my real project it doesn’t:
#ifndef HOVERBUT_H
#define HOVERBUT_H
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QHoverEvent>
#include <QEvent>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>

class hoverBut : public QPushButton
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit hoverBut(QWidget *parent = nullptr){
        setAttribute(Qt::WA_Hover);
        setText("not Hover");
    }

protected:
    bool event(QEvent * e) override
    {
        //qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << e->type();
        switch(e->type())
        {
        case QEvent::HoverEnter:
            setText("Hover !");
            return true;
        case QEvent::HoverLeave:
            setText("not Hover");
            return true;
        default:
            return QPushButton::event(e);
        }
    }
};

class MainView : public QGraphicsView
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainView(QWidget *parent = 0){
        setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
        //setWindowState(Qt::WindowFullScreen);
        scene = new QGraphicsScene;
        setScene(scene);
        hoverBut* but = new hoverBut;
        scene->addWidget(but);

    }
protected:
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event){
        scene->setSceneRect(0,0,this->width()-5,this->height()-5);
    }
    QGraphicsScene* scene = nullptr;
};
#endif // HOVERBUT_H

In my project, when not clicked, I get the events:
virtual bool hoverBut::event(QEvent*) QEvent::UpdateRequest
virtual bool hoverBut::event(QEvent*) QEvent::WindowDeactivate
virtual bool hoverBut::event(QEvent*) QEvent::UpdateRequest
virtual bool hoverBut::event(QEvent*) QEvent::Paint

But I need to click on the widget to get:
virtual bool hoverBut::event(QEvent*) QEvent::HoverEnter

In the minimal example that I provide, I do not need to click to get HoverEnter.

Please provide a proper [mre].

Tried to do some guesswork and fill the missing parts, but cannot reproduce. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

It work with minimal code, I don't understand why it doesn't in my real project

Then take your real project, and keep removing parts of it until you will notice that the problem is gone. That's how you will identify offending piece of code. Then put this piece of code back in place to have the problem reproducible, and remove anything else that doesn't make the problem go away. That's how you will produce MCVE that can be included in your question to make it answerable.

The issue was another widget overlapping my button, and if I use setZvalue(1) it works. This overlapping widget wasn't blocking the click, but it does block the hover event... It is weird, but anyway it works now.

It's not weird, it's actually an expected behavior caused by bad implementation: if you provided a proper MRE as requested we could've explained why to begin with. Right now both your question and this answer aren't really useful to anybody, because there's no immediate way to understand what caused the problem, nor any proper code to reproduce it. Either consider to properly update your question with a valid MRE, or delete it: in its current form it will be closed/deleted anyway sooner or later, unless it's appropriately updated, as right now it won't be useful to nobody else but you.

Use setMouseTracking(true); when constructing your widget.

Mouse tracking only ensures that MouseMove events are handled even if no buttons are pressed. Hovering should not be influenced by that.

Note to reviewers: Wrong answers are not Very Low Quality. The correct review is "Looks OK".
